When printing a document that used Segoe UI font, the document data become random words
I have issue using Segoe UI font. When i tried to print from my apps, it become random words. Example: word "Page" it become "F_j_k_l..."
By the way i used Epson L3210 printer.
Did anyone know how to fix it?
